# Android studio test not running says 0 passed and tests cancelled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/drbfraser/CRADLE-Android). [This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMJw0.png). [And this is another warning that appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ano.png)

I can see the test running in the emulator only when I run the whole androidTest folder, but IDE doesn't seem to know that. When I try to debug the test, it just keeps saying [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zCcu.png) forever.

I have tried downgrading espresso but the result was the same. Several other posts suggest adding `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` but its already there.